# How to loop over each file in a directory, if and only if the directory contains the .csv files?

Tags: shell-script, files, scripting

```
/dir1/--$ ls
1.txt 2.ssl.txt
```

If the `dir1` directory has the given `.csv` files, then only process the files listed in the `.csv` in a loop one after another.

Here as the `dir1` does not have any files listed in the`.csv`, then it doesn't have to enter into the loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
find dir1/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.csv" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d '' f; do
  # process file
  echo "$f"
done
```

- `find` searches only for files (`-type f`) with the ending `.csv` (`-iname "*.csv"`), only in `dir1` and not in its subdirectories (`-maxdepth 1`). The filenames are printed delimited by a null character (`-print0`) to cope with special filenames.
- The `while` loop reads the input delimited by the null character and stores the filename in a variable called `$f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
for csvfile in */*.csv
do
    echo "Processing $csvfile"
done
```

This assumes the directories are all under the current directory. If they're not please update your question to show where they really are.